# Using user-defined schema methods on documents returned from populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm finding that when I retrieve a subdocument through populate(), I can't use the methods that I have defined on the subdocument's schema.

On the User schema I've defined a getPermissions() method. I have a Post schema which includes a User field which references the User schema. When I call populate('user') on a post, it returns the user data correctly but the getPermissions() method is not defined.

Is that normal behaviour? Is there any way to get access to these "schema methods" on the subdocument?

Comment: The methods defined in the schema should be there. Can you edit your question to include code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is no, you can't use methods on an object returned from populate() because it is serialised.